# Converting standard to feature linked annotation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, annotation

Is there a way in ArcGIS 10.2.2 & ArcSDE 9.3 to convert standard annotation to feature linked annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot convert annotations that were *originally created* as standard to feature linked. However, if they *were* feature linked at some point, you can theoretically restore that link provided the annotation's linking attribute is still present.

See this Esri KB article for more information: http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30509

Comment: any suggestions as to any clever workarounds?

Comment: @Matt No idea if it would work or not, but I'd start by creating some FL annotation of the features with a few examples. Check that classes's attribute table and see what's available. In theory it should be possible to either do some sort of join between the feature attribute table (the label had to come from somewhere), *or* create all new FL annotation for everything, strip off the linking attributes and put them on your original annotation, and then either recreate the relate (see link) or maybe even cheat and just rename files. *Somehow* you have to join between features and annotations.