# Loading feature linked annotation to existing sde Database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, annotation

I have feature linked annotation (composite) in sde Databese and i need to add / load annotation from another Database FGDB, is there a way to do this? or i need to make all the prosses again (Lable and than convert to annotation and create new Anno layer)?

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148835/

Comment: The best success I've had doing this is by using workspace to XML then import the XML into SDE.

Comment: This way will build a new layer, but I need to add to exists layer